# What is Pan for in pan-caspase?

Tags: molecular-biology, apoptosis

A simple question (I could not find it on internet): What is Pan for in pan-caspase? Is it any different from the term 'caspase' ?

Comment: can you tell the context of that phrase? If in case of inhibitor it could mean that it inhibits all caspases. Similarly with antibodies: a pan-caspase antibody would bind to all caspases.

Comment: there is no specific context but i now realized that it is usually used as pan-caspase inhibitor in the articles i was looking at. just to be sure: can we then say that pan is the opposite of specific?

Comment: yes you can say that.. but we generally use the term "caspase-`x` inhibitor", where `x` is that specific caspase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term pan, in my opinion, is perhaps one of the most vague that exists in science! I can partley answer this question (ironically as vague as the term pan) by referring you to the term pan-neuronal. A pan neuronally expressed genes has features, which include the expression of many "generic" genes required non-specifically for neuronal function, such as components of the synaptic vesicle machinery, so pan-neuronal genes are not neurone class specific (http://www.wormbook.org/chapters/www_specnervsys/specnervsys.html). So with that token pan-caspases are a term referring to a general caspase activity/function/structure and not a specific caspase type activity but I would welcome any corrections or edits to this response.

Answer (score 1):

Pan is referring to all. So a pan-caspase inhibitor is a molecule that inhibits all caspases indiscriminately.

Note that [pan](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pan) means all in Greek.